# ¿Cómo obtener mas elementos de un combobox?

Tags: java, netbeans, txt, visualización-de-datos

Tengo unos **combobox** anidados uno es de hospitales y otro es de los tipos de servicios que tiene el hospital, cuando selecciono un hospital me trae los servicios de ese hospital, pero la tabla servicio tiene un varios datos, y requiero obtener los demás elementos de la tabla servcio al momento de seleccionar el servicio:

```
introducir el código aquí// controlador donde ejecuto los cbx anidados  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
  if(e.getStateChange()== ItemEvent.SELECTED){
cbxGetSetHospital hospitalCbx = (cbxGetSetHospital) vistaNdietas.cbxHospi.getSelectedItem();
DefaultComboBoxModel serv = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboServicios.mostrarPisos(hospitalCbx.getIdHospital()));
vistaNdietas.cbxPisoHospital.setModel(serv);   
  }  
}
introducir el código aquí// consulta a la DB donde obtengo los valores del cbx (set and get) public Vector<cbxGetSetServicios> mostrarPisos(Integer idHospital){
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  conexion conn = new conexion();
  Connection con = conn.getConnection();
  Vector<cbxGetSetServicios> datos = new Vector<cbxGetSetServicios>();
  cbxGetSetServicios dat = null;
  try{
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_pisoservicios WHERE col_id_HospitalFK=" + idHospital;
   ps= con.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = ps.executeQuery();

   while(rs.next()){
    dat = new cbxGetSetServicios();
    dat.setIdPisoServicios(rs.getInt("colum_idPisoServicio"));
    dat.setNombreServicio(rs.getString("colum_nombrePisoServicio"));
    dat.setNoCamas(rs.getInt("colum_noCamas"));
    datos.add(dat);
      }
    }catch(SQLException e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
  return datos;
```

}

Lo que requiero es el dato de **colum_noCamas** y asignarlo a un **.txt** que cada vez que seleccione un servicio me traiga el dato. ¿Alguien me puede orientar?

Comment: Necesitas poner algo de codigo porque asi no hay mucha forma de como ayudarte.

Comment: gracias por escribir.

Answer (score 0):

me costo pero lo logre...
Espero le sirva a alguien 
Tengo dos comboBox anidados, uno de hospitales y el otro de cada servicio o piso que tiene el hospital, la tabla servicio tiene un id,tipoServico, numeroCamas, al momento de seleccionar el combobox de servicios me trae el id y el tipo de servicio, pero requeria tambien el dato de numerodeCamas para asignarlo a un txtField(esto lo hice en mvc).

pues lo unico que tube que hacer es instanciar el getysetServicio y acceder al getCamas.
importante(tienes que poner el escucha ActionListener y/o addItemListener). pero bueno les dejo el codigo para que entiendan.introducir el código aquí

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getStateChange()== ItemEvent.SELECTED){// Escucha el cambio
    cbxGetSetHospital hospitalCbx = (cbxGetSetHospital) vistaNdietas.cbxHospi.getSelectedItem();// mandas a llamar el gety set del primerComboBox
    DefaultComboBoxModel serv = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboServicios.mostrarPisos(hospitalCbx.getIdHospital()));
    vistaNdietas.cbxPisoHospital.setModel(serv); 
    cbxGetSetServicios servCbx = (cbxGetSetServicios)vistaNdietas.cbxPisoHospital.getSelectedItem();
    vistaNdietas.txtNoCamas.setText(String.valueOf(servCbx.getNoCamas())); // asigno el numero de camas al txtField 
      }
    }